# Pre-Order Traversals Of All Possible Binary Trees Given In-Order Traversal

Tags: c++, binary-tree, inorder, preorder

I was looking at questions on binary trees, and I came across the following: 
Given the in-order traversal of a binary tree, print the pre-order traversals of all possible binary trees satisfying the given in-order traversal.

For e.g, if the in-order traversal is: {4, 5, 7}
The possible trees are:

```
4         4           5         7       7
 \          \       /   \      /       /
  5          7     4     7    4       5
   \        /                  \     /
    7      5                    5   4
```

Therefore, the pre-order traversals are:

```
4 5 7  
4 7 5 
5 4 7 
7 4 5 
7 5 4
```

The solution I came up with:
Traverse the given in-order list. Upon each iteration, select an element from the list and make it the root of our tree. All elements preceding the current one will be part of the left subtree and all elements succeeding it will form the right subtree. We can then recursively do the same for the left and right subtrees.

For instance, in the above example, I begin by selecting 4 as the root of my tree. Now since there are no elements preceding 4, I cannot have a left subtree. I look at the remaining elements. They will form the right subtree. I select 5 to be the root of this subtree. For this, I am only left with one choice: to construct the right subtree of 5 from 7. That gives the first tree of the example.

Now, I keep 4 as the root, and instead of selecting 5, I select 7 as the root of the right subtree of 4. This leads me to the second tree of the example above.

That much is fine. The problem comes up with the code. I've spent quite sometime on translating the above solution to code. But I haven't been completely successful.

This is what I've tried in C++:

```
void solve(vector<int> inOrder, int beg, int end, string &s, bool &flag)
{
    for(int i = beg; i <= end; ++i)
    {
        s += to_string(inOrder[i]);
        flag = false;
        solve(inOrder, beg, i - 1, s, flag);
        solve(inOrder, i + 1, end, s, flag);
        if(s.size() == inOrder.size()) {flag = true; cout << s << endl;}
        if(s.size() && flag) {s.pop_back();}
    }
}
```

I use a string to store the current permutation of elements in the pre-order traversal. Elements are appended to the string when a permutation satisfies the in-order traversal.

Naturally, elements must be subsequently removed from the string to make way for other permutations. However, I haven't been able to figure out *when* to remove an element. In the above code, I append an element the first time it is encountered, and I start removing elements when the string has size equal to that of the in-order list.

So, let's say I begin with 4. I append 4 to the string. I do the same for 5 and then 7. Now the string size equals the total number of elements. So I remove the last one. My string is now `45`. Since there are no more possible combinations with the current string, I remove 5. I'm left with 4. Now, I can append 7 and then 5, leading to `475`. This works fine in this case, but I haven't been able to make it work for other combinations. It fails when I begin by making 5 as the root, instead of 4.

So my question is, how exactly should I proceed to solve the above problem? Am I even doing it the right way? Or should I give up this approach and think of something else? If yes, what direction should I proceed in?

I'm not looking for an exact solution, only a hint as to what I'm missing or what I could do better.